# Dynamics 2016/365 - Active Directory 2016 compability mode

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

one of my customers is planning to upgrade their environment to Active Directory 2016 mode. Since the software requirements page for Dynamics 365 only lists the modes up to 2012 - are there any experiences/informations if Dynamics 2016/365 is compatible with this mode?

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx

```
The following editions of the Windows Server 2016 operating system are supported 
for installing and running Microsoft Dynamics 365 Server:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
```

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is regarding the Active directory modes, not teh server version.

Comment: I never heard about "modes", never faced any issue while setting up CRMs and I can't find any doc about it (in MSDN, google or otherwise), do you have some info links to share (adding them to the question is even better) ? This puzzles me.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx

Active Directory modes: 

The computer that Microsoft Dynamics 365 Server is running on must be a member in a domain that is running in one of the following Active Directory directory service forest and domain functional levels:

    Windows Server 2008

    Windows Server 2008 R2

    Windows Server 2012

    Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Kudos to google for not fetching that one... I'll ask the colleagues

Answer (score 0):

To conclude:

I contacted the Dynamics Technical Partner support for that:

Active Directory mode 2016 is not supported in Dynamics 2016/365. At the moment is it not known, when - or if - that will change in future.